# Match a nested object field present in an array in lookup aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two collections `Projects` and `Users`.

`Projects` has a budget field with the following: 1)`amount` and 2)`currency`

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(...),
  type: 'typeA',
  budget: {
    amount: 123,
    currency: 'USD'
  }
}
```

`Users` has a field called `bids` which contains list of objects with fields `amount` and `currency`.

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(...),
  name: "User name",
  bids: [{amount: 123, currency: "USD"}, {amount: 342, currency: "INR"}]
}
```

I am trying to join `Users` with `Projects` using a lookup aggregation.

```
db.Projects.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
          from: "Users",
          let: { projectAmount: "$budget.amount", projectCurrency: "$budget.currency" },
          pipeline: [
            {$match: {
              $expr: {
                $and: [
                   { $eq: ["$bids.amount",   "$$projectAmount"] },
                   { $eq: ["$bids.currency", "$$projectCurrency"] }
                ]
              }
            }}
          ],
          as: "matchingBids"
    }
]);
```

But I am always getting the empty result though I have some matching objects in the Users collection. I've gone through the official docs and internet but didn't find anything helpful. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please add the expected output in your question too. It will help in fixing the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$in` operator with full object and array

- pass budget object in `let`
- check `$in` condition with `bids` array

```
db.Projects.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Users",
      let: { budget: "$budget" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $in: ["$$budget", "$bids"] }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "matchingBids"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oP0DX-E9Vg8)

> **WARNING**:
>
> The above approach will work only when order of fields in object and array of object should be same, below examples will not work!
>
> ```
> budget: { amount: 123, currency: "USD" }
> bids: [{ currency: "USD", amount: 123 }]
> ```
>
> OR
>
> ```
> budget: { currency: "USD", amount: 123 }
> bids: [{ amount: 123, currency: "USD" }]
> ```

---

**EDIT:**

After some workaround i found a way to make sure to match exact fields to overcome above situation,

- `$or` condition with both possibility of fields position `{amount, currency}` and `{currency, amount}`

```
db.Projects.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Users",
      let: { budget: "$budget" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $or: [
                {
                  $in: [
                    { amount: "$$budget.amount", currency: "$$budget.currency" },
                    "$bids"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $in: [
                    { currency: "$$budget.currency", amount: "$$budget.amount" },
                    "$bids"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "matchingBids"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KPXN8SsmQoQ)